# How to figure out the last part-number in a MapReduce job output directory

Tags: mapreduce, hdfs

I am wondering if there is a way of figuring out the last part number in a MapReduce output directory? I want to move some files in another directory to the directory but I would like to make them appear as if they are part of the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a map only job it's the number of input splits. For a reduced job its the number of reducers. Note that both values are zero based with regards to the output numbers for the files (0 to n-1)